# D3 Pack layout - appending event to child element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I am using D3 Circle pack layout and was wondering if it is possible to append events to child element?

I use this code to append the event:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.child")
   .on("click", ChildClick, true);

function ChildClick(d, i) {      
    return true; 
  }
```

But the event doesn't fire, I have debugged it with FireBug and it does not step into the event function. Also I cannot do simple Hover event. I can append events to all parent elements though.

---

I have solved it partly. This has been caused by css:

```
circle.child {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If I remove this it fires events also for child elements, but the zooming will look not so nice. Will have to work on fixing this now..

Comment: you should add a jsfiddle, so we can debug the code for you

Comment: Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pz3m/2/